# Android Application portrait mode

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-orientation

I am developing an android application. This Application is in Portrait mode. I changed the manifest file like below

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/customTheme" 
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <activity android:name=".Favorites"
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DBHelper">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Find" 
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
</application>
```

which is working fine upto large screen. When I opened it in **Extra-large** screen the screen is not coming good, i.e all the controls in the view are diagonally cutting.
**see the image:**
[image]

When I remove the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` tag from the manifest file my Xlarge Screen is appearing normally. I am not able to understand the problem exactly can any one help me in solving this. I want my application should be in portrait mode only.

Comment: I must confess I really don't see a reason to force the user of a super large screen to use a certain orientation, especially given the inconveniences which go hand in hand with this. It's one of the outstanding features of Android to handle rotation and a broad variety of devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide layout for xlarge-port..So that ur layout can adjust in xlarge screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep different layouts for different screen sizes,For that you need to create different layout for different screen size and put it into different folders named as

1. layout-large : for portrait mode of large size screen
2. layout-medium :for portrait mode of medium size screen
3. layout-xlarge :for portrait mode of xlarge size screen
4. layout-large-land :for landscape mode of large size screen
5. layout-medium-land :for landscape mode of medium size screen
6. layout-xlarge-land :for landscape mode of xlarge size screen

Now Android OS will choose appropriate screen automatically.

Comment: after creating layout-xlarge folder also the screen is appearing same.if i did not provide a layout-xlarge folder the images should be small but y the screen is crosing like that.it is because of resolution or it will hapend with real device also

Comment: Have you changed your xml file according to your folders?

Comment: No i didn't changed the xml i kept the same xml file.i need a design like that .

Comment: You have to change xml files also.Putting into this folders simply means, at run time android os will calculate screen size and choose xml files from appropriate folder.